# Server library could not be loaded and the dynamic link library LIBPQ.dll

Tags: c#, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, arcgis, postgresql-8.4

Please i have a serious problem here. When i want to debug my application in visual studio i have this message box error  : **"The ordinal 133 could not be located in the dynamic link library LIBPQ.dll"**. this dll belongs to PostgreSQL 8.3.8. Note that i'm using also ArcSDE 10. After that it give me the following message in visual studio **"Server library could not be loaded"**. Here there is the code that i use for my connection to arcsde. Normally it did work before in my other applications.

```
class sdeConnection
    {
        IWorkspace m_pWorkSpace;
        NpgsqlConnection m_pCnx;
        IFeatureWorkspace m_pFeatWorkSpace;
        ISqlWorkspace m_pSqlWorkSpace;
        string m_version;               

// Version of the database to be used for the update data
    public sdeConnection()
    {
        // ArcSDE Connexion 
        Type factoryType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesGDB.SqlWorkspaceFactory");
        IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = (IWorkspaceFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType);

        // create the connection to the database server
        IPropertySet pCnxProp = new PropertySet();
        pCnxProp.SetProperty("dbclient", "PostgreSQL");
        pCnxProp.SetProperty("serverinstance", "localhost");
        pCnxProp.SetProperty("instance", "5432");
        pCnxProp.SetProperty("authentication_mode", "DBMS");
        pCnxProp.SetProperty("database", "sde");
        pCnxProp.SetProperty("user", "sde");
        pCnxProp.SetProperty("password", "geoserver");

        // Creation of the workspace
        m_pWorkSpace = workspaceFactory.Open(pCnxProp, 0); **it gave the second error here (Server library could not be loaded)**

        // Npgsql Connextion 

        m_pCnx = new NpgsqlConnection("server=localhost;port=5432;database=sde;user=sde;pwd=geoserver");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found where was the problem. When installing postgres , i added the path of it to the environment variable. So it created a copy of library of postgress in the windows32 folder . So there was a consfusion between libraries. So i removed the path in the environment variable and i deleted all librairies created in the win32 folder. it work very well now :).